# Reading method-level properties using JUnit + spring-test

Tags: junit, spring-test

What is the best way to use spring-test with JUnit to read property files specific to a *test method*?
The following bean illustrates the *intent* to search method-level, then class-level, then package-level, then root-level property files:

```
<bean name="properties" class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer"    >
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:properties.xml</value>
            <value>classpath:*/properties.xml</value>
            <value>classpath:*/*/properties.xml</value>
            <value>classpath:*/*/*.properties.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I've considered using/subclassing `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` or `SpringMethodRule`, but so far, neither a viable nor elegant solution has occurred to me. spring-test offers a variety of promising class-level annotations, but the stumbling block is that I want to be able to find a method-specific file, e.g.:

```
classpath:myPackage/myClass/myMethod.properties.xml
```

Comment: What do you mean by you "want to be able to find a method-specific file"? The Spring `ApplicationContext` itself doesn't know anything about test methods, and the Spring TestContext Framework doesn't support loading a test `ApplicationContext` per test method. So where do you plan to load them and for what purpose?

Comment: My test has a 'SpringContextRule' like http://www.alexcollins.com/tutorial-junit-rule.  My test has another rule based on http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TestName.html that provides access to the names of the test class and test method.

Comment: For each test method, there is a property file that by convention is named after the method, e.g. 'foo.properties.xml', 'bar.properties.xml', where 'foo' and 'bar' are test method names.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for an *algorithm* that helps you to look up classpath resources based on the current method, you can take inspiration from the `ServletTestExecutionListener` in the *Spring TestContext Framework*, specifically the [`detectDefaultScript()`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/test/context/jdbc/SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java#L279-L312) method.

Regards,

Sam *(author of the Spring TestContext Framework)*

Comment: I will have a look and respond with feedback. Thank you!